# Android: Null Pointer Exception During PagerView Instanciation

Tags: android, layout

I'm getting a null pointer exception during runtime. I'm pulling in RelativeLayouts from 2 XML files for the PagerView, which I seem to have messed up. Any idea what's causing the error?

Thanks for any help!

I have two of these XML files that have this same structure--
player_turn_solution_component.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/player_turn_solution_component"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/solutionCaption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="what do you see?" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/solutionInput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/solutionCaption"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My instanciation function:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        //Our specific component (TextView or ImageView, depending on posision
        //is placed inside a RelativeLayout that acts as a container
        RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(pagerContext);
        TextView caption = new TextView(pagerContext);
        caption.setText("View: " + position);
        caption.setTypeface(typeface);
        caption.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        container.addView(caption);

        RelativeLayout optionLayout = null;
        TextView optionCaption = null;

        if (position == 0) {
            optionLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_turn_solution_component);
            optionCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solutionCaption);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            optionLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_turn_clue_component);
            optionCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clueCaption);
        }

        container.addView(optionLayout);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(container,0);  //get the container ready
        return container;   
    }
```

And the LogCat output:

```
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3158)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3145)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at my.app.PlayerTurnActivity$HelpPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PlayerTurnActivity.java:136)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1375)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2257)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
07-06 09:30:22.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8418):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: My new Activity contains the following, but crashes with the same NPE, but only when I swipe to change the pager view.

```
if (position == 0) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player_turn_solution_component, null);                
        optionLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.player_turn_solution_component);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player_turn_clue_component, null);    
        optionLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.player_turn_clue_component);
    }

    container.addView(optionLayout);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(container,0);  //get the container ready
    return container;
```

Comment: optionLayout  is null. Where you have inflate it?

Comment: what is code at line No:36 in your PlayerTurnActivity.java file?

Comment: Line 36 is empty. Also, I didn't inflate it anywhere. That must be it!

Comment: Try RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(YourActivityName.this);

Comment: Sorry, not 36 Just **See Line No:136**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_taht_have_player_turn_solution_component, null);
```

and

```
 if (position == 0) {
            optionLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.player_turn_solution_component);
            optionCaption = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.solutionCaption);
        }
```

Comment: That helped get the first view to show up, but it crashes when I switch to the next pager view. I added the new code to my original question.

Comment: I think  layout `player_turn_clue_component` does not have `player_turn_clue_component` and `clueCaption` ?

Comment: LogCat says the issue is at container.addView(optionLayout);, and when I switch the two layouts it runs, but again crashes when the pager view is changed. Slightly swiping, to the point where I can see the next view but without actually letting go on the next view doesn't crash it.

Comment: strange..try `container.addView(v);`